# упрощение блока кода на js(таймер по выходу из сессии)

Tags: javascript

Это общий код, но интересуют конкретно строчки var `timeoutCount = #{timeoutBean.getTimeout()};`и `var sessionTimeOut = timeoutCount;`как можно тут упростить?

```
var timeoutCount = #{timeoutBean.getTimeout()};
var sessionTimeOut = timeoutCount;
function startTimer(timeoutCount) {
  if (#{request.userPrincipal != null}) {
    if (timeoutCount == 0) {
      window.location.href = '/logout?sessionTimeOut=' + sessionTimeOut;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      startTimer(timeoutCount - 1);
    }, '1000');
  }
}
```

таймер запускается при помощи `<body onload="startTimer(timeoutCount)">`

Comment: А что это вообще за конструкция `#{}` ? Какой-то шаблонизатор? Ruby? Java?

Comment: Darth, это из области jsf. Задает стартовое время, сколько должен считать счетчик.

Comment: Почему нельзя просто сделать `var sessionTimeOut = #{timeoutBean.getTimeout()};` и везде вместо `timeoutCount` оперрировать `sessionTimeOut`? Где у вас ещё используется `sessionTimeOut`? Может оно не просто так сделано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускаем счётчик от 0:

```
const sessionTimeOut = #{timeoutBean.getTimeout()};
function startTimer(timeoutCount = 0) {
  if (#{request.userPrincipal != null}) {
    if (timeoutCount >= sessionTimeOut) {
      window.location.href = '/logout?sessionTimeOut=' + sessionTimeOut;
    }
    setTimeout(startTimer, 1000, timeoutCount + 1);
  }
}
```

таймер запускается при помощи `<body onload="startTimer()">`

UP еще проще:

```
if (#{request.userPrincipal != null}){
    const sessionTimeOut = #{timeoutBean.getTimeout()};
    window.onload = () => setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = '/logout?sessionTimeOut=' + sessionTimeOut;
    }, sessionTimeOut * 1000);
}
```

И в body onload не надо указывать

Comment: Darth, всмысле непонятно? проблема в этих двух строчках, var timeoutCount = #{timeoutBean.getTimeout()};
var sessionTimeOut = timeoutCount. Чтобы не делать лишний запрос #{timeoutBean.getTimeout()} надо упростить, чтобы так и оставался 1 запрос, но при этом чтобы не было переприсваивания. Мб, можно что-то с этим сделать?

Comment: @АлександрПлющев у вас одна переменная используется как счётчик, а вторая хранит оригинальное значение. Можно запускать счётчик от 0 до оригинального значения, сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: сейчас проверю)

Comment: @АлександрПлющев А зачем вам дёргать таймаут каждую секунду? Не проще сразу `setTimeout( --тут logout-- , sessionTimeOut * 1000)`

Comment: а так будет работать?) покажите код как должно выглядеть

Comment: @АлександрПлющев обновил

Comment: все очень четко, спасибо за помощь)